# Remove 'Chapter' text from chapter headings and have chapter number on the same line as chapter title

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chapter formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/chapter-formatting)

Apologies if this is something simple, but I seem to be searching in the wrong place for an answer. I have a document of type `report`. It is currently generating my chapters as follows:

Chapter 1

*Name of Chapter*

I just want it to be:

1. *Name of Chapter*

I had a few latex documents which used to generate it in the way I want using this command:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{#1}{}}
```

However it does not seem to be having any effect on my new document. What am I missing?
I am using the latest MiKTeX 2.9 and Texmaker 3.5.2.

Comment: very similar to the question [Chapter formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `titlesec` package. The following example shows how to implement it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\it}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Name of Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove numbering before the title? Istead of "1 Foo"; "2 Bar" to have just "Foo" and "Bar"?