# Change chapter heading format

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chapter formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/chapter-formatting)

Could someone help me with this problem with my document?

Instead of generating the following:

```
% % % %

Chapter 2

Title

% % % %
```

I would like the following text:

```
% % % %

2 Title

% % % %
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: There are many similar questions on this site, with answers, which you may find with the search facility.  If none of these help, you will need to tells us which documentclass you are using.  You will get most help by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
\makeatletter
\def\chapter{\cleardoublepage\secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{{\raggedright\Large\bfseries\thechapter\space #1\par\nobreak\vskip 10\p@}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{{\raggedright\Large\bfseries #1\par\nobreak\vskip 10\p@}}
\makeatother
```