# Chapter Style in Lyx

Tags: lyx

Im using Lyx for my lab reports, but i dont like the way it displays chapters. How can i change it so it shows 1. "Chapter Name" and not

1. Chapter
   "Chapter Name"
   ?

Every help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  I think we need a minimal working example (MWE) see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4488/15925 - we at least need to know which document class you are using.

Comment: Consider to use [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package

Comment: If you don't mind the other changes, try changing the document class to KOMA-script report.

Comment: well its to long to post here... :-(

Comment: the KOMA-script is much better, thanks alot! now im just asing out of curiosity: woulnt it be possible to just add some latex-commands in the preamble?

Comment: @gerberli Well, yes, see e.g. [Chapter formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18604), but I was too lazy/short on time to find out the details when I posted my previous comment. (By the way, to make sure users are notified of your comments, write `@username` as I did here. You, as the owner of this post is always notified, the rest of us aren't.)

Comment: You could redefine the string used by adding the following to your latex preamble. `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}`, although babel could complicate the issue. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-the-word-chapter-to-something-else

Comment: What document class are you using,? Without more information, the easiest could be switch to an article type class (`article`, `paper`,`scrartcl`....) so you can use sections as first level. If you need more levels, you would use `memoir` and `\chapterstyle{section}`. If you need another class,  it would be nice to know ...