# Remove Appendix title from the document

Tags: spacing, appendix

I am new with LaTex and I am trying to add an Appendix section to my thesis with the following code:

```
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
  \section{ROIs}
  \input{Appendix/Appendix A}
    \clearpage
  \section{Water mask based on the MNDWI}
  \input{Appendix/Appendix B}
    \clearpage
```

When I run the code, the Table of Contents looks perfect (see attached picture below). The problem comes when I check the Appendix section from the document which looks as follows (see picture below).

[image: Table of Contents]

[image: Appendix section]

First of all I would like to remove the title "Appendix" which is redundant. Secondly I would like to move the title of "Appendix A" to the top of the page together with the title of the section "ROIs" in order to fit the Figure I want to attach as an Appendix in the same page (the figure is quite big).

HI have been trying to introduce spacing functions between \chapter{Appendix} and \section{ROIs} but it does nothing.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/chapter-formatting

The accepted answer in this link might help you (it uses the package titlesec - see their docs for further details on the command). Note that the pair of commands \titleformat and \titlespacing can be used only after the \appendix command, so that they don't affect the chapter titles in the main body of the document.

Comment: I think that we need more information from you in the form of an MWE that starts with `\documentclass...` and ends with `\end{document}`. What class are you using? Are you using the `appendix` package? Are you ... ?