# How can I change the chapter naming?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

Sorry for the bad english. When I type `\chapter{Title}` I want to have

```
Section ''Title''
```

instead of

```
Chapter 1
```

or whatever the current chapter number is.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question does not really provide sufficient information to give a solution, this is dependent on the documentclass and the packages used, and possibly on other settings you already have in your document. However, in most of these cases you can use the [titlesec](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/chapter-formatting for something similar to your requirement.

Comment: As you are not provided `MWE`, not able to suggest exactly, but you can try with `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Section}`...