# How do I set my page numbers to the same size through the whole document?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, page-numbering, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{fontspec} % compile w/XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{Perpetua}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrule}{} % Remove the horizontal line from the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\fontfamily{ppl}\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\thepage} % set the footer centred and using Perpetua 11 font

\newcommand{\appendixchapter}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681868/269662
  \cleardoublepage
  \fancyfoot[C]{\fontfamily{ppl}\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\thepage}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter\arabic{page}}%
  \chapter
}

\begin{document}
  \fontsize{13pt}{15.6pt}\selectfont
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \kant[1]
  \appendix
    \appendixchapter{An appendix}
    \kant
    \appendixchapter{Another appendix}
    \kant
\end{document}
```

The page numbers are set to Perpetua 11, which compiles like that. However, it only appears to do so on the first page of the (appendix) chapter. Then, the numbers get bigger again. How do I set the page numbering to Perpetua 11 throughout the whole document?

Comment: What is this `\fontsize{13pt}{15.6pt}\selectfont` suppose to do? It will be overwritten as soon as `\normalsize` is called somewhere in the code.

Comment: That was the only way I was able to set the size to 13pt globally. `\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{fontsize}` or something like that didn't work for me.

Comment: There is no support for 13pt in book. Or most other classes for that matter. You'll probably need a class that allows you you define your own `.clo` file (for example `memoir` supports this, not sure if `extbook` does, the KOMA bundle probably has an interface for it as well)

Comment: BTW the footer size is because the title page of a chapter does not use the `fancy` style, it often uses `plain`. Look in the `fancyhdr` manual, there should be information about changing the plain style as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `\fontsize{13.5}{15.6}\selectfont`. Instead use `fontsize`.

With `\usepackage[fontsize=13.5pt]{fontsize}`, the baseline skip would be set to `16.19995pt`, so it's easy to fix `\baselinestretch` in order to obtain `15.6pt`: just divide to find that

`15.6/16.19995 = 0.96296593508004654335`

and indeed issuing

```
\linespread{0.96297}
```

produces `\baselineskip=15.6pt`. I'd also set `\topskip` to the font size.

This said, your code has mysterious `\fontfamily{ppl}` instructions that are to be removed.

Now the text height is set to 550pt, but

`(550-13.5)/15.6 = 34.39102564102564102564`

so you don't have an integral number of lines in your pages. You need to reduce a bit the text height:

`13.5+34*15.6 = 543.9`

But roundings accumulate, so it's better to use `543.91pt`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[fontsize=13.5pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec} % compile w/XeLaTeX
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setmainfont{Perpetua}[
  Path=/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/,
  BoldFont=* Bold,
  ItalicFont=* Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=* Bold Italic,
]

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove the horizontal line from the header

\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\thepage
} % set the footer centred and using Perpetua 11 font
% fix also the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\thepage}%
}

\newcommand{\appendixchapter}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681868/269662
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter\arabic{page}}%
  \chapter
}

% final setting: fix the baseline skip
\linespread{0.96297}
\setlength{\topskip}{13.5pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{543.91pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\kant[1]

\appendix

\appendixchapter{An appendix}

\kant

\appendixchapter{Another appendix}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, there are a lot of valuable comments in there. However, this seems to have inverted the issue to where the first chapter page number is larger than the other page numbers.

Comment: @BlueIris You're right! We also need to change the `plain` page style. Fixed.

Comment: Any quick ideas as to why this would interfere with a TOC, List of Figures, List of Tables, but not a list of Listings?

Comment: @BlueIris What interference?

Comment: Their content disappeared, leaving behind only the headings.

Comment: @BlueIris Sorry, this requires a new question with the details and an example.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684533/why-is-my-cross-linking-system-interfering-with-the-toc