# How do I get rid of "0. Chapter title" in \frontmatter book chapter titles while maintaining Verdana 14pt? I would just like "Chapter title"

Tags: chapters, book-class

I had to mess with the settings of the `book` class to match people's will. Removing the "Chapter X `\\` Xtitle" part and replacing it with "X. Xtitle" for instance. In verdana 14 (so I compile with XeLaTeX, also because the body text is written in Perpetua, 13pt).

Anyway, I whittled my code down to the following MWE. How do I get rid of "0. Chapter title" in `\frontmatter` `book` chapter titles? But I do want to keep "Chapter title".

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec} % compile w/XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{Perpetua}
\newfontfamily\chapterfont{Verdana}

\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/chapter-formatting
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \chapterfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\bfseries
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \thechapter.\ % <-- Chapter # (without "Chapter")
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    #1\par\nobreak% <------------------ Chapter title
    \vskip 12pt% <------------------ Space between chapter title and first paragraph
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
    \chapter{Preface}
    \lipsum
    \chapter{Abstract}
    \lipsum
    \tableofcontents
\mainmatter
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \lipsum
    \chapter{Another chapter}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Any thoughts?

---

Edited to include `fontspec` and some settings in the package to remove the most egregious errors in the MWE.There are a few commands that are terminated with a space which is code copied from [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/chapter-formatting).

Comment: your example doesn't compile without error.

Comment: The usual way to have a chapter without a number is to use \chapter*.

Comment: Of course! And then I can add them to the TOC semi-manually. I keep forgetting the simple things. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, well, that negates the whole verdana 14-thing, which is a pity. I've lost my previous enthusiasm and am still working on this issue.

Comment: Using `\chapter*`  you should also redefine `\@makeschapterhead` (notice the 's' for starred) as you did for `\@makechapterhead`  just omitting the `\thechapter`.

Comment: I did and it will not take verdana 14pt, it will just default.